# RcppArmadillo, OpenMP and RNG seeds

Tags: r, openmp, rcpp, armadillo, rcpparmadillo

What is currently the best solution to allow seed setting when using openMP?

Simple example:

```cpp
#include "RcppArmadillo.h"
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace arma;

// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
vec rngtest(int N, double seed, int cores){
  arma_rng::set_seed(seed);

  omp_set_num_threads(cores);
  vec out(N);
    
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
  for(int k=0; k<N; k++){
    out(k)=randn(1)[0];
  }
  
  return(out);
}
```

**Issues**

Firstly, one can't set seeds in Armadillo (anymore?) when calling from:

```r
rngtest(10,2,4)

Warning message:
In rngtest(10, 2, 4) :
  When called from R, the RNG seed has to be set at the R level via set.seed()
```

Now if I use set.seed and use let's say 4 cores, I do get deviations:

```r
set.seed(123)
rngtest(10,2,4)
            [,1]
 [1,]  1.0034247
 [2,] -0.5099541
 [3,]  1.5406472
 [4,] -1.2821739
```

```r
set.seed(123)
rngtest(10,2,4)
            [,1]
 [1,]  1.0034247
 [2,] -0.5099541
 [3,]  1.5406472
 [4,] -0.5437432
```

**Some thoughts**
I think once can figure the sequence in which computations are assigned and try to arrange the results in the right order. How do I do that and is it generating computational overhead at all? Shouldn't. I think this is a general armadillo/openMP question, regardless of calling via Rcpp or not.

I'd also love to be able to set RNGs for armadillo independent from R, even while calling code from R. It'd be so nice when developing packages for different environments.

Answer (score 4):

There are several topics comingled here.

1. We default to RNGs from R for convenience of R users, but there is a toggle you set via a `#define` to turn this off
2. With OpenMP you can also simply ignore the R RNGs, use your own and rely one of the parallel RNGs such as [sitmo](https://cran.r-project.org/package=sitmo) or [dqrng](https://cran.r-project.org/package=qrng).

Comment: Yes, those were 2 questions in one. Thanks for pointing me to sitmo and reminding me of the toggle in `#define`. When setting the RGN in cpp code, does this affect R's RNG as well? I like to simulate data in R (often setting the seed) but when I estimate using MCMC, I often just want a random seed.

Comment: The C API for R has not convenient seed setter (as the behind it is complicated; state for the RNGs is multidimensional) which is why you only see `set.seed(...)` from R.  The rest if up to you, either sequantially or in multi-threaded code.